# Flash drive not detectable

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have a 4 GB flash drive, and one day it works, but then all of a sudden, nothing will recognize it. I tried my laptop, my PC, my schools computers, even my stereo system. None of them detect it. And it's only a couple years old! Can anybody help?

EDIT:
What I mean by not detectable is that I cannot do anything with it. The computer acts as if I never plugged the drive in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be corrupted in some way.

First check if the device is even detected - it should be detected as a disk drive *and* a usb device in device manager. The equivilent for this in linux would be to check lsusb and /dev/ for appropriate entries

[image]

If its not there, its a clear functional fault, and the drive is completely dead.

If it is, check the if there is partition in disk management - it should be blue if there's a proper partition on it in your case, it would be black. You *could* format it, or run recovery software like testdisk on it to get data out, and the disk would be usable.

[image]